# Installer Mixed MAPEI Primer T with Self Leveling Plus - Will it Work?

Tags: flooring, primer

Installer is used to using RS LevelQuick, but I went to Lowes and bought MAPEI Level Plus and Primer T instead.  Anyway, I saw he was mixing the bottle of Primer T with the Level Plus, he also said it was 1 bottle to 1 50 Lb Bag. We had 10 bags that have been used so far.

I looked this morning and walked around on the floor (subfloor is plywood). Everything appears normal. Floor will be LVP.

Could this possibly be OK?  Yes I know it is not as per manufacturers instructions.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not at all an expert, but I believe these primers are polymer based and one doesn't "cancel" the other. So since indoors, very likely ok. No benefit either. Net zero bang for lots of buck. Call manufacturer to confirm. They might give a legal answer ("well, we don't comment on other products"), so then call a local concrete finisher. They might speak from experience and be better trained on cement additives.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense, right now just walked on with a finish coat and it seems ok, the finish coat was done with levelquik.